# spi-fly weaving methods with parameters

Tags: java, apache, osgi, spi, aries

When using Apache Aries SPI-Fly to enable SPI in OSGI, I cannot call the methods with parameters for dynamic weaving. I've used the following bundles:

- org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle-1.0.2.jar
- asm-all-5.0.4.jar
- org.apache.aries.util-1.1.1.jar

Here are the headers in the maven bundle plugin section of my pom.xml:

```
<SPI-Consumer>org.apache.aries.spifly.examples.client2.impl.Activator#getSpiProvider(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</SPI-Consumer>

<SPI-Provider>org.apache.aries.spifly.examples.client2.impl.Activator</SPI-Provider>
```

I tried to read /META-INF/services/org.apache.aries.spifly.mysvc.SPIProvider:

```
public static SPIProvider getSpiProvider(final String factoryId, final String fallbackClassName){

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        String serviceId = "META-INF/services/" + "org.apache.aries.spifly.mysvc.SPIProvider";
        URL r = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(serviceId);
        System.out.println("*** Found resource: " + r);
        System.out.println("*** First line of content: " + new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r.openStream())).readLine());

        //return null for the moment
        return null;

    }
```

If I remove the parameters from the getSpiProvider method and change the SPI-Consumer to the following maven-bundle-plugin entry in pom.xml

```
<SPI-Consumer>org.apache.aries.spifly.examples.client2.impl.Activator#getSpiProvider()</SPI-Consumer>
```

Any idea what went wrong here?. Can't we use methods with parameters for weaving?

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to achieve with that code. Spi-fly mainly covers the usage of the ServiceLoader. You seem to use it for a completely different case as it seems.

Comment: Check these samples http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/spi-fly/spi-fly-examples/spi-fly-example-resource-client-bundle/ http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/trunk/spi-fly/spi-fly-examples/spi-fly-example-resource-provider-bundle/

Comment: I've had to examine the code of SPI-Fly recently and I thought that it didn't handle (non-`ServiceLoader.load()`) methods with parameters correctly or at all. However, it does seem like it should technically work since it only adds some method calls before and after the desired method call: https://github.com/apache/aries/blob/e43c57447a09e833bfab3b30aff554cc6ec09998/spi-fly/spi-fly-weaver/src/main/java/org/apache/aries/spifly/weaver/TCCLSetterVisitor.java#L205-L206. Unfortunately, I can't look into this right now, but maybe this was or is a bug (and maybe it's been fixed).